# query string format passing Username and password

Tags: angular

I am working with angular 7 with Web API

I have this url:

```
'http://localhost:8089/api/Logins/CheckPassword?ID=[UserID]&Password=[Password]';
```

I tried, but I am not getting this format.

Comment: Do you want to make API call with these parameters (Id, password)?

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible. Can you please try to formulate exactly what you want to achieve, what does not work and what you wrote in code?

Comment: Yes. Please thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by using HttpClient

Sample function

```
  sampleApiCall(): Observable<any> {
    let __params = new HttpParams();
    __params = __params.set('ID', 'UserID');
    __params = __params.set('Password', 'Password');

    return this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8089/api/Logins/CheckPassword', {
      params: __params
    });
  }
```